# C++ isprint() equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have seen many "home grown" implementations of a JavaScript equivalent to the C++ `isprint()` function.

Here's the one I'm currently using:

```
 function isprint(char) {
     return /^[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\] ^_`{|}~-]*$/.test(char);
 };
```

My question is, is there a "stock" function call that provides the same functionality?

Comment: What about support for non-ASCII characters...? What purpose are you using this for?

Comment: I'm using it to convert an array of bytes, as returned by the Node.js net-snmp module, into a string.  net-snmp returns octet strings as arrays of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

not without regex. Your example is good or you could use this (but it works only for char up to 127)

```
function isPrint(aChar)
   {
       myCharCode = aChar.charCodeAt(0);

      if((myCharCode > 31) && (myCharCode <  127))
      {
         return true;
      }

      return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

try ([reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacenonprint.html))

```
function isprint(char) {
     return !( /[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/.test(char));
}
```

this is checking if the character that is passed is a non-printable character and returns the inverse of the test.